# 100 : ORA-01403: no data found in Oracle APEX 5.0 while importing file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created two separate data imports using Data Loading feature in Oracle APEX. Let's say that 1 is importing CSV file into table that doesn't have primary key and the 2 is importing CSV file into table that has a  primary key that is required. But it is important to mention that this value is automatically generated by Oracle database:

```
"ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

So, two imports work perfectly fine, but with 1 I get no error and correct number of rows that are imported. With 2 I also have notification that 29 rows are imported but I also get error that import failed for that exact 29 rows. In database everything is fine but user get the error for every row:

```
100 : ORA-01403: no data found
```

Tell me, what's the problem with Oracle APEX so it shows that error? How to fix it or disable so that user will not get confused. Thanks.
At final step of Data load process the error looks like this:

```
Sequence    Action  Error   OTHER_COLUMNS                                                                                                                                               
1   INSERT  100 : ORA-01403: no data found  OTHER_COLUMNS_DATA
```

Comment: Do you have any transformation rules or table lookups?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, for both Data loads I have up to 5 transformations that evaluate correct data format and divide `money` into `currency` and `value`. None of that values are `NOT NULL`. Still, they are all not empty.